# How to optimize a self-joining select with an inner join to another table

Tags: mysql, inner-join, query-performance, self-join

I have a message board with messages, threads and boards all stored in a single "pages" table. I would like to list all the messages with their ancestry of thread and board. The self join for this is fast, but when I include the message authors using an inner join to another table, the query slows down to multiple seconds. Is there some way to better structure the query?

The database looks like this:

```
pagetypes
type        | typename
———————————————————
15           board
16           thread
17           message 


pages
pageid  |  type | parentid    | authorid | title                
————————————————————————————————————————————
1          15      null          1        "BigBoard"
2          16      1             1        "Introductions"
3          17      2             2        “Hello everyone!”
4          17      2             1        “Welcome!”
5          16      1             1         “News and Gossip”
6          17      5             3        “Whats new?”

users
id    | name
————————————————————
1       "Peter"
2       "Paul"
3       "Mary"
```

My select query is:

```
select p.title as message_title, u.name, t.title as thread_title, b.title as board_title
from pages as p
join pages as t on p.parentid=t.pageid
join pages as b on t.parentid=b.pageid 
join users as u on p.authorid=u.id
where p.type=17
```

The result looks like this:

```
message_title       |   name    |   thread_title       |    board_title
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
“Hello everyone!”       Paul        "Introductions"         "BigBoard"
“Welcome                Peter       "Introductions"         "BigBoard"
“What’s new?””          Mary        "News and Gossip"       "BigBoard"
```

If I take the user out of there, the query (on 400K pages) is 30 ms. With the user added to the request, the query takes up to 3 seconds.

Here are the table descriptions:

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
  `pageid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `parentid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `authorid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pageid`),
  KEY `text_key` (`parentid`,`type`),
  KEY `type_key` (`type`),
  KEY `byAuthor` (`authorid`,`type`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
)
```

Comment: Please add EXPLAIN resuolt of your query also show table for your tables to see which indexes you have already

Comment: Per nbk's suggestion, I have added the sql for the tables including the indexes. I'm not sure what other indexes might help.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical.) Please research before considering posting. That includes basics of SQL optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [ask]

Comment: Thanks for the great advice philipxy. I did not realize EXPLAIN existed. I'll start analyzing the query with it and continue researching SQL optimization/performance.

Comment: (My)SQL DBMS "KEY" does not mean FK. Constraints are not indexes. Learn what each is. Where you have FKs not implied by other FKs declare them. The DBMS can use FKs to optimize. They also have default indexes. Read everything in the manual re FKs. (And every other functionality you use.) PS One thing you can learn re performance is google SO questions about it & see what people are asked to give as well as answers. Also google meta.SO. And there are entire books. Some free on the web eg in pdf. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it. I added a LEFT JOIN to the users which brought the query down to 30 ms.

```
select p.title as message_title, u.name, t.title as thread_title, b.title as board_title
from pages as p
join pages as t on p.parentid=t.pageid
join pages as b on t.parentid=b.pageid 
LEFT JOIN users as u on p.authorid=u.id
where p.type=17
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. So if this helped, which forces the DBMS to go through all of the left table, it is because it wasn't before & inappropriate default statistics suggested some other plan. So if you want to learn what was going on & how to help yourself in the future, edit your question per the comments. Also the 2 queries don't always return the same results so you didn't actually fix the 1st query performance.

Comment: Thanks for the advice philipxy - This was my first time posting a question here, so I certainly have room for improvement! Per the queries not always returning the same result, I am testing them with an extended query that orders the results by a createdate, so the results should be the same?

Comment: Look at the definition I just gave for left join. Its result differs from right when there can be unmatched left table rows. Here, when/iff some authors are not users. But relevant DDL & data is missing. But if authors are users (eg there's a FK from a to u) you should still use inner because it captures the intent since there can't be unmatched rows. You should find out why the original was slow. The orginal may not even still be slow--caching, other changes between tests, not actually measuring the right thing, etc. PS Read everything in the manual re constraints, indexes & optimization.